# Can't enter the password

Tags: linux, passwords, keyboard-layout, gnome3, login-screen

I have a password in English in Fedora GNOME. There is no correct keyboard input method on the login screen. I tried booting with runlevel 3 to hop onto runlevel 5, but the session finishes in order. Is there a way to add the correct keyboard layout?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Are you lacking a password input field? Can you possibly include a picture of what you are seeing?

Comment: @Burgi No, password input field is here. I have no suitable layout* to enter the characters of the password since it is in other alphabet. edit: *yes, keyboard layout.

Comment: So your keyboard layout is in another language other than English and your password use the [Roman characters](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_alphabet#New_alphabet) which you can't type on your current keyboard layout? Is that correct?

Comment: There has to be a way for Linux to know which keyboard layout to start with. It's a basic requirement for international users, but I don't know what it is. Until you find a real solution to this problem, you can work around it by booting into single user mode (as root) and changing your password to one that works with the keyboard layout that you currently have. To boot into single user mode - to reset passwords

Boot from any live cd
load as single (root)
chroot /dev/sdaX
where sdaX is the root (/) linux partition
run passwd and assign new passwords
reboot

Comment: @Joe Thank you, it *is* the solution. Why don't you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Linux supports international keyboards at startup, but it's a basic requirement for international users, so I'm sure it does.

Since your immediate issue is that the character set used by your current password doesn't match the character set in use at startup, the simplest thing to do is to just change your password.

You can do that by booting into single user mode (as root) and changing your password to one that works with the keyboard layout that you currently have.

To boot into single user mode - to reset passwords (or fix almost anything else which stops you from having a working system):

Boot from any live CD (or live image flash drive). This will almost always give you easy root access.

As root, `chroot /dev/sdaX` where `sdaX` is the root (/) Linux partition which you would normally boot from.

If you don't know which partition that is, you can first run `gparted /dev/sda` and look for the partition labeled as "/".

Run `passwd your-user-name` to assign a new password for your user (and/or for root - if you have a root password.)

Shutdown the live distro and remove it from your system then Reboot normally.

All should be fine and you can make whatever further changes you need now that you have normal access again.